# How do I paginate for every slug?

Tags: python, django

I was wondering what is the right way to paginate items from a slug page. I tried something, but I can't seem to figure out how to properly pass Courses that belong to that Faculty and to paginate them by 1 course per page.
Here is what I tried:

```html
def faculty_filter(request, faculty_slug):
    qr = get_object_or_404(Faculty, faculty_slug=faculty_slug)
    query_list = Course.objects.get(qr)
    query = request.GET.get('q')
    if query:
        query_list = query_list.filter(Q(name__icontains=query))
    paginator = Paginator(query_list, 1)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        courses = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        courses = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        courses = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    context = {
        'courses': courses,
        'faculties': Faculty.objects.filter(faculty_slug=faculty_slug),
        'departments': Department.objects.all(),
        'studies': StudyProgramme.objects.all(),
    }
    return render(request, 'courses/filters/faculty_filter.html', context)
```

Note: Courses do not directly belong to a Faculty. I have four models bound by foreign keys in this order: Faculty > Department > StudyProgramme > Courses.

Comment: Do you have a list of courses? Better to have a list of object, and then you can paginate them one by one or more.

Comment: Of course I have courses in my model.What do you mean by list of object ?

Comment: Do you want to display courses in the templates one by one? right. query_list = Course.objects.get(qr) this is a get, not a list. How will you have more than one in order to display them as paginator

Comment: I also tried Course.objects.filter(qr) and i get error that Faculty is not iterable.

Comment: with filter, you to have some codes like:      Course.objects.filter(field=qr)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how is your models definition, but if you have a foreign key connecting `Faculty`, `Department`, etc. you can navigate all the way back:

```
query_list = Course.objects.filter(programme__department__faculty__slug=faculty_slug)
```

Or, alternatively, since you have the faculty instance:

```
qr = get_object_or_404(Faculty, faculty_slug=faculty_slug)
query_list = Course.objects.filter(programme__department__faculty=qr)
```

Please note that I'm assuming that `Course` is connected to `StudyProgramme` via foreign key named `programme`, and `StudyProgramme` is connected to `Department` via foreign key named `department`, and so forth.

Basically two underscores (`__`) is used to navigate between the foreign key relationships.